The content of the public folder of nuxt3 is modified but not effective?
Please help. I developed a web using Nuxt3. I found that after running with nodejs, the new robots.txt file under my public folder, I modified the content of robots.txt, but refreshing my web did not take effect. I must re-execute pnpm run build after modifying the robots.txt file, so that it will take effect. Why, isn't the public directory of nuxt3 a static resource directory?
1.This is the directory after my nuxt3 project is built
https://i.sstatic.net/QS4TpYOn.png
2.Then I ran this nuxt3 project using nodejs
3.At this time I modify the robots.txt file in the public directory, But it doesn't work on the browser
4.I am confused. If I want to modify the robots.txt file after publishing the web developed by nuxt3 to the server, do I have to rebuild it after modifying the development environment and then update it to the server?
